# Wrap email quotes with html element

Tags: php

I'm wondering if I could handle the following situation with a single function or regex call. Given the folowing input:

```
Some text

> Foo
> Bar
>> Baz
> Foo
```

The output should be:

```
Some text

<blockquote>
Foo
Bar
    <blockquote>
        Baz
    </blockquote>
Foo
</blockquote>
```

The following two functions do handle this situation, but I think there must be a more elegant way to handle it. I thought about regular expressions, but could not think of any pattern that replaces the input with the output (see above).

```php
<?php
function toArray($str, $currLevel = 0, $i = 0) {
  $return = array();
  $lines = explode("\n", $str);
  for($j = count($lines); $i < $j; $i++) {
    $line = trim($lines[$i]);
    $level = preg_replace('/^((?:>|\s)+).*/','\1', $line);
    $level = substr_count($level, '>');
    if($level == $currLevel) {
      array_push($return, preg_replace('/^((?:>|\s)+)(.*)/','\2', $line));
    }
    else if($level > $currLevel) {
      array_push($return, toArray(join("\n", $lines), $currLevel  + 1, &$i));
    } else if($level < $currLevel) {
      $i--;
      return $return;
    }
  }

  return $return;
}

function toQuote($lines) {
  $return = "<blockquote>\n";
  foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(is_array($line)) {
      $return .= toQuote($line);
    }
    else {
      $return .= $line . "\n"; 
    }
  }
  $return .= "</blockquote>\n";
  return $return;
}

$str = <<<INPUT
  Some text

  > Foo
  > Bar
  >> Baz
  > Foo
INPUT;

echo toQuotes(toArray($str));
```

Comment: Don't know if it's of any help, but Markdown does this; however, only with a newline after the inner quote.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't much more elegant, but maybe you like it:

```
$text = "Some text

> Foo
> Bar
>> Baz
> Foo
";

function clean($text) {
  $result = "";
  $lines = explode("\n", $text);
  foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
    $lines[$key] = preg_replace('/(>)+ /', '', $line);
  }
  return join("\n", $lines);
}

function quotes($text, $level = 1) {
  $search = str_repeat(">", $level);
  $fstpos = strpos($text, $search);
  $sndpos = strrpos($text, $search);
  $sndpos = strpos($text, "\n", $sndpos);
  $middle = substr($text, $fstpos, $sndpos + 1);
  if($fstpos === false or $sndpos === false)
    return clean($middle, $search);
  $fst = clean(substr($text, 0, $fstpos), $search);
  $snd = clean(substr($text, $sndpos), $search);
  return $fst . "<blockquote>\n" . quotes($middle, $level + 1)  . "</blockqoute>" . $snd;
}

echo quotes($text);
```